# Subset of a sorted array

Tags: algorithm

We are given N candy. The ith candy has a  height Hi and the color Ci
Ci<=K

We have to found  how many strictly increasing ( in height ) colorful subsequences are there? 
A subsequence is considered as colorful if every of the K colors appears at least one times in the subsequence.

For Example:
  4 candy are given with their height and colors.

```
1 1
3 2
2 2
4 3
```

only two valid subsequences are (1, 2, 4) and (1, 3, 4).

[Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/101hack18/challenges/candles-2)
How can we solve this problem which algorithms are used to solve this problem?

Comment: It is not sorted. It has no subsets as it's not a set. And it's candle, not candy.

Comment: @n.m it has subsequences though

Comment: @NiklasB. could you help